# How to save a file history?

Tags: files, history

Is there any packages or extension that will save a file history when you save the file?

Example when I save the file it will create a file history of the file and on the later time when I save it again, it will create another history of it.

It look like something a snapshot of file save or a backup.

Comment: Emacs has built-in support for creating numbered backups. Look for Backups in the manual, https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Backup-Names.html#Backup-Names

Comment: thanks I will try to look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Emacs keeps just one older "backup" of every file you edit. If you edit a file called *foo*, then the backup file is called *foo~*.  Whenever you save a new version of the file *foo*, the previous version is saved as *foo~*, and the previous backup file is discarded.

You may request that Emacs save multiple backup files, thus yielding a version history of your file.  If you set the variable `version-control` to `t`, then Emacs will save multiple older versions, up to a maximum controlled by the variables `kept-old-versions` and `kept-new-versions`.

(If you're at all serious about keeping history, though, I recommend that you learn to use a dedicated version control tool such as `git`.)